# Double pointer function argument and CComPtr

Tags: c++, atl, smart-pointers

I'm not sure of this way of using CComPtr inside of a function which has an argument expressed as a double pointer:

```
HRESULT D3DPresentEngine::CreateD3DSample(
    IDirect3DSwapChain9 *pSwapChain, 
    IMFSample **ppVideoSample
    )
{
    // Caller holds the object lock.

    D3DCOLOR clrBlack = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

    CComPtr< IDirect3DSurface9 > pSurface;
    CComPtr< IMFSample > pSample;

    // Get the back buffer surface.
    ReturnIfFail( pSwapChain->GetBackBuffer(0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pSurface ) );

    // Fill it with black.
    ReturnIfFail( m_pDevice->ColorFill(pSurface, NULL, clrBlack));

    // Create the sample.
    ReturnIfFail( MFCreateVideoSampleFromSurface(pSurface, &pSample));

    // Return the pointer to the caller.
    *ppVideoSample = pSample;
    (*ppVideoSample)->AddRef();

    return S_OK;
}
```

I have a doubt about the last assignation + AddRef call.

Are they OK for you?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK, but could be simplified:

```
HRESULT D3DPresentEngine::CreateD3DSample(
    IDirect3DSwapChain9 *pSwapChain, 
    IMFSample **ppVideoSample
    )
{
    // Caller holds the object lock.

    D3DCOLOR clrBlack = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

    CComPtr< IDirect3DSurface9 > pSurface;

    // Get the back buffer surface.
    ReturnIfFail( pSwapChain->GetBackBuffer(0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pSurface ) );

    // Fill it with black.
    ReturnIfFail( m_pDevice->ColorFill(pSurface, NULL, clrBlack));

    // Create the sample.
    ReturnIfFail( MFCreateVideoSampleFromSurface(pSurface, ppVideoSample));

    return S_OK;
}
```

In your code, the `AddRef` is necessary, because `pSample` will `Release` when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

The more idiomatic version would be

```
// Transfer the pointer to our caller.
*ppVideoSample = pSample.Detach();
```

If you want copy semantics rather than transfer, you would use

```
pSample.CopyTo(ppVideoSample);
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignment and dereference for `AddRef()` are correct.

When `MFCreateVideoSampleFromSurface()` is called, the second argument to it is the location where the pointer to the interface should be stored. You use `&pSample` to obtain the address to pass to the function. This matches the `IMFSample **` type required. Note that the `&` operator on `CComPtr<>` via `CComPtrBase<>` returns the correct type.

[CComPtrBase::& operator @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31k6d0k7.aspx)

`ppVideoSample` is type `IMFSample **` as well, which requires the `*` operator to dereference the interface pointer. That yields a pointer of type `IMFSample *`, which you can call with the `->` operator to access `AddRef()` and other functions on the interface.